# Recursion Trouble in Java

Tags: java, recursion, restart

I'm trying to get an output that looks like this:

3
2
1
"restart"
1
2
3

: using this code recursively.:

```
public static void restart(int n){

    return; //fill in here 
}
```

Comment: If you having trouble with this task I would suggest trying to solve it yourself to get a little training, no offense.

Comment: this is what I filled in ---->  if(n==0) System.out.println("restart")' else{ System.out.println(n); restart(--n); -----> but I dont know how to count back up

Comment: @javarecursion instead of posting code in comments use [edit] option to include it in question.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void restart(int n){
    if (n == 0) {
      System.out.println("\"restart\"");
      return;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
    restart(n-1);
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

should do it.

Comment: This stops at restart, but it should continue with 1,2,3

Comment: @for3st it looks ok to me...

Comment: You're right, I read is as an else, Ill take it back ;)

Comment: +1 This is both simple and lesser-order(3) than my answer(6) needing less memory

Answer (score 1):

Writing a recursive method entails answering these two questions:

1. When will the recursion stop? (More formally, what's the **base case**?)
2. How will the recursion continue?

Note that there may be multiple cases for recursive continuation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class statik
  {
   static int countDown=3;static boolean down=true;


 static void downward(int c,boolean down)
 {
    if(c!=0)
    {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Restart");
    }

    if(down)
    {
        c--;
    }
    else
    {
        c++;
    }

    if(c<1)
    {
        down=!down;
    }
    if(c>countDown)System.exit(0);
    downward(c,down);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
{
     downward(countDown,down);

}


 }
```

Output:

```
  3
  2
  1
  Restart
  1
  2
  3
```

Comment: correct, but not very elegant, also missed the method signature restart(int n); I know nothing that a wrapper could not fix, but i guess the problem lies in keeping the signature

Comment: Hmm. Keeping both signature and integer in just an integer. Maybe creating a thread inside can solve. Maybe giving -1 to restart when n=0 can solve.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for

```
public static void restart(int n) {
    System.out.println(n); 
    if (n == 1)
        System.out.println("restart");
    else
        restart(n-1);
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

---

version with some additional info

```
public static void restart(int n) {
    //lets pring numbers first
    System.out.println(n); // <-------------------------------------+
                                                                 // |
    if (n == 1)                                                  // |
        //then after number 1 lets pring "restart"               // |
        System.out.println("restart");                           // |
    else                                                         // |
        //if n is not 1 we continue recursion with lower number  // |
        restart(n-1); // -------------------------------------------+
    //after we stopped creating new recursive calls (when n==1) its time to print 
    //rest of numbers
    System.out.println(n); //I used n-1 instead of --n earlier so I can use n here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void restart(int n){
    if (n == 0) {
      System.out.println("\"restart\"");
      restart(3)
      return;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
    restart(n-1);
}
```

This will keep printing

```
3
2
1
"restart"
1
2
3
.............
```

I think that's what you want.